# Is there a webserver software which its directives are in an intuitive (“human-like”) language?

Tags: web-server

When I write Bash/PHP/JavaScript code writing it is much more of a human-like language to me than say "Apache PCRE" or "Nginx directives" which both feel to me as pretty much "machine languages" (not 0101010101 1000001111 yes but still something very hard which requires tremendous amounts of focal knowledge to properly understand). I don't enjoy working with Apache PCRE and Nginx directives as I am with Bash/PHP/JavaScript, if don't feel the sense of reward I feel with Bash/PHP/JavaScript.

Is there a (significantly popularity-growing) webserver software which its directives are in an intuitive ("human-like") language (and are more like Bash/PHP/JavaScript)?
I think I should examine such software, community and culture as it might making my webmastering much simpler and even more rewarding.

Comment: IIS with it's extensive GUI for configuration immediately comes to mind. Anything with a GUI is an win for the "intuitive" part.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the config files for https://caddyserver.com/ are fairly intuitive and straightforward to use